# Convert ko.toJSON back to observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following observable array:

```
self.users = ko.observableArray();
```

which has an items of the following object:

```
function user(id, name, score) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.score = ko.observable(score);
}
```

I need to store this observable array locally in user's computer (simplified example) so I use localstorage and `ko.toJSON` function for this. This works fine and all the data is stored in localstorage, including the `score` item, which is an observable itself. The problem is that I can't convert this string back to observable array. When I do `JSON.parse` and pass it to `self.users` `score` isn't observable any more. Is there any function like `ko.parse` to revert back `ko.toJSON`?

Comment: The [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) can probably help with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually pretty straightforward. However you initially constructed the `self.users` collection is the same way you will construct it with the JSON data. This is one example:

```
function User(data) {
    this.id = data.id;
    this.name = data.name;
    this.score = ko.observable(data.score);
}

...
//inside viewmodel
var storage;
self.store = function() {
    storage = ko.toJSON(self.users());
    self.users.removeAll();
};
self.load = function() {
    var parsedUsers = JSON.parse(storage);
    self.users(ko.utils.arrayMap(parsedUsers, function(u) {
        return new User(u);
    }));
};
```

Here is [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X3DmR/) using this method.